# What does stringsAsFactors=FALSE mean?

Tags: r

What does `stringAsFactors=FALSE` mean?

The R code looks like this:

```
my.iris<-read.csv("iris_morphology.csv",stringAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

> stringsAsFactors
>
> logical: should character vectors be converted to
> factors? Note that this is overridden by as.is and colClasses, both of
> which allow finer control.

Source: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/utils/html/read.table.html